# Send value of option tag with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, database

Im adding users to a database and i decided to add a new field, which is this

```
<div class="input-field col s4">
        <select ng-model="register.regData.area" >
          <option value="Web">Web Dev</option>
          <option value="Android">Android</option>
          <option value="Ios">Ios</option>
          <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
          <option value="Desing">UX & UI</option>
      </select>
        <label>Area</label>
      </div>
```

to be more clear, this is working

```
  <div class="col s6">
              <input value="Male" type="radio" id="male" ng-model = "register.regData.sex" />
              <label for="male" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Male</label>
          </div>
```

but the database display this: `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595ef73540320c1a463a0c0b"),
    "area" : null,
    "sex"  : "male",
    "__v" : 0
}`

here is the controller:

```
.controller('regCtrl', function($http, $location, $timeout, User) {
  var app = this;
  this.regUser = function(regData) {
    app.errorMsg = false;
    app.loading = true;
    User.create(app.regData).then(function(data) {
      if (data.data.success) {
        app.loading = false;
        app.succesMsg = data.data.message + '... redirecting';
        $timeout(function(){
          $location.path('/');
        },1000);
      } else {
        app.loading = false;
        app.errorMsg = data.data.message;
      }
    })
  };
})
```

my questions is, how can i get the right value of the option selected?

Comment: Can you post your  controller code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784318/angularjs-getting-the-value-of-a-selected-dropdown-option-in-a-variable

Comment: @RohanKawade here is